# Where usually custom build activity is downloaded when we open Process tab in Build Definition?

Tags: c#, android-activity, build, tfs

I have the following problem. There is a custom build process which is using the custom build activity. I've been opening this build some time ago, and everything was good. But, after some time, the custom build activity and build process has changed, got new arguments and some other changes. This activity has been updated on the server source control path, which is set in build controller settings. But, it seems that this activity doesn't want to be downloaded on my desktop, because when I open build definition, I'm getting error that my new custom type couldnot be resolved.

I've tried to build this activity by myself and place it to the folder, which contains devenv.exe, and this "solved" problem - my build process has been opened. But It is not normal.

What should I do to normally open my build definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of custom assembly folder defined for controller is downloaded to temp folder and loaded by studio once (im not sure if proper version increments for dlls would solve this - haven't tried) when opening the process tab on build definition. You either have dlls somewhere that overrides this (GAC, VS private assemblies) or your studio has been running for long time.

Remove the one you put along devenv, restart studio, check GAC and private assemblies, you can use Studio and attach debuger to other instance and review loaded modules this can help you pinpoint where the item is comming from.

To remove assembly run following from Visual Studio command line: gacutil /u "YourAssembly"

For studio assemblies i believe this is the folder: Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've solved this problem and got some new knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've solved this problem and got some new knowledge.
The custom activity assemblies which is necessary to resolve TFS Build Process is downloaded here in one of subfolders which names consists of GUID: C:\Users\sarapkin\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild.
To find out this I used Procmon. 

The problem has been solved when I asked admin to open TFS Source Control, find my assembly and forcibly add my AD account and give it read permissions on this file.

Comment: Intresting, will note that. Havent been in scenario where i didnt have access to source.